# How to handle pointer events in both a Component and its Container?

Tags: codenameone

Suppose I have a custom slider component, many of those, in a BoxLayout.Y-scrollable-Y Container. The custom slider components cover all of the container.

What I want is that the slider components handle pointerDragged in the X-Axis while still having the Container beeing draggable in order to scroll the "list" just as if there where no slider components at all.

The only way I can think of to achieve this seems to be a hack. I'd do that by overriding some methods in the slider components in a way that it would forward pointer event to its Container like this:

```
        @Override
        protected int getDragRegionStatus(int x, int y) {
            return Component.DRAG_REGION_LIKELY_DRAG_XY;
        }
        @Override
        public void pointerDragged(int x, int y) {
            super.pointerDragged(x, y);
            {
                // Handle X-axis dragging here
            }
            boolean focusable = getParent().isFocusable();
            try { // handle Y-axis dragging there
                getParent().setFocusable(true);
                getParent().pointerDragged(x, y);
            } finally {
                getParent().setFocusable(focusable);
            }
        }
```

I doubt that this is the way this should be done. But just as a wrote above this is the only way I can think of how to make it work with Codename One.

But how would You get this working?

Answer (score 0):

Why is it a hack?

You're trying to achieve a special case, you can do it by overriding the form pointer events or binding a listener to the form itself.

Comment: You didn't answer the question. I very specifically asked what You would be doing to achieve that.

But to answer Your question on my question: My "solution" to forward a pointer event to a parent Container relies on internals that could change and that I don't fully understand. So yes - I call it a hack.